# Red5, there is a simple way of testing it?

Tags: red5

I want to try [Red5](http://www.red5.org/). Is there a ready-to-use Linux installation just for testing it?

Answer (score 0):

There's already a [virtual appliance for vmware](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/282043) available by the looks of things, although this is somewhat out of date as it's based on version 0.8.

However, [installation looks pretty trivial](http://wiki.red5.org/wiki/Install), so you could download a copy of 
[Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org/)/[VMWare](http://www.vmware.com/), your Linux distro of choice and create your own VM for testing if you require a more up to date version for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Grab a tarball and run it. The only thing you may need to install is Java. The pre-built download links can be found here: https://github.com/Red5/red5-server
In addition, if you want the absolute latest version, you can get it from the Apache build server here: https://builds.apache.org/view/M-R/view/OpenMeetings/job/Red5-server/